# List all directory types visible and hidden (with dot in front) in current directory with terminal on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, ls

I'm trying to use `ls` to list all directories visible & hidden in current directory and have had no luck.

I'm using `ls -d */` to visible directories and `ls -d *./` to get hidden directories.

How can I combine these commands into one? Or does someone have a better way of using `ls` to view all directory types?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command if your terminal can handle [brace expension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to show hidden and not hidden directories only:

```
ls -d {.,?}*/
```

or this one (activates matching also `.` by wildcard using [shopt](https://ss64.com/bash/shopt.html)) for a shell:

```
shopt -s dotglob
ls -d */
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -al | grep '^d'`
will list all nodes in the current dir and grep only the ones where the entry starts with d (which stands for directory)

another approach is using `find`:
`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d`